# Complex SQL query for ShoppingCart

Tags: sql, database, database-design, select

I've been trying to figure out how to query a shopping cart database to find all Orders that contain tangible items (items can be downloadable, therefore, not shipped) that have not been assigned a UPS tracking label. I haven't been able to do it.

The involved tables are as follows:

```
// dbo.Inventory - details about the individual product being sold
- ProductID int primary - Name nvarchar - IsDownloadable bit -
| 5                     | Awesome Shirt  | 0                  |
| 7                     | An Audio Track | 1                  |

// dbo.ShoppingCart --("ShopID" groups the items in the cart)
- CartID int primary - ProductID int - ShopID char (guid) - Quantity int -
| 2                  | 5             | e854a982c9264a72   | 4            |
| 3                  | 7             | e854a982c9264a72   | 1            |

// dbo.Orders - Order information (shipping address, etc)
- OrderID int primary - ShopID char(x)    - BillingInfoColumns -
| 13                  | e854a982c9264a72  | Name,Address,etc   |

// dbo.Tracking - Shipments' (note: a shipment can contain several items) tracking numbers
- TrackingID int primary - OrderID int - TrackingNumber char(x) -
| 5                      | 13          | Ze5Whatever...         |

// dbo.ShippedItems - Maps a ShoppingCart's shipped items to tracking numbers
- ShippingID int primary - TrackingID int - CartID int - QuantityInShipment int
| 6                      | 5              | 2          | 3                      |
```

Hopefully the above provides an reasonable approximation of how the DB is designed.

So, to clarify what I *think* I need:

- SELECT all OrderIDs that have NOT had ALL their tangible items Shipped.
- Non-tangible items are IsDownloadable = 1
- Must take into account the ShoppingCart.Quantity column. If we order 4 t-shirts we may put them in one box (with one UPS tracking label). Then again, we may put 2 per box. Or we may put one pair of jeans with one shirt in one same box (again, with one tracking label)...etc.

I have been concocting crap with endless JOINs and nested WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM)s to no avail. Sadly, I can't seem to wrap my head around it...I'm still waiting for my eureka moment.

I'm relatively new to SQL and database design so any information or (constructive) criticism will be greatly appreciated. Feel free to poke holes in the design of the database itself if you think that will help. :-)

---

```
// I wish I could run this on my brain right now...
// (Neurons, apparently, are "excitable")
UPDATE Brain SET Neuron = 'Excited' WHERE Cortex = 'SQL'
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what I came up with thanks to Benoit Vidis. This is the actual query I'm using on my real tables/data:

```
    SELECT 
        d.OrderID
    FROM
        Person.ShoppingCart c
    JOIN
        Inventory.Item i
    ON
        i.ItemID = c.ItemID
    JOIN
        Orders.Details d
    ON
        d.ShopID = c.ShopID
    LEFT JOIN
        Orders.Shipping s
    ON
        d.OrderID = s.OrderID
    LEFT JOIN
        Orders.ShippedItems si
    ON
        s.ShippingID = si.ShippingID
    WHERE
        i.DownloadableMedia = 0 AND
        d.Billed = 1 AND
        d.Ordered = 1
    GROUP BY
        d.OrderID
    HAVING
        SUM(c.Quantity) > CASE WHEN SUM(si.Quantity) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(si.Quantity) END
```

Comment: Wow. Am I right in thinking that ItemID is actually a ProductID, and that LabelID is a TrackingID? There might even be more synonyms, but I can't figure it out because there are so many possibilities. If I'm right, I think you want to fix that ASAP, because even if it doesn't confuse you now, it will later. And it sure as heck makes it confusing for us SO people (and whoever will maintain your code). [How about just updating the question to use consistent naming for now?]

Comment: Yikes, sorry about that. My actual tables don't have synonyms flying around like that. Its fixed now. +1 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it using the HAVING clause. In MySQL, it would give something like:

```
SELECT 
  c.OrderID,
  SUM(c.Quantity) AS tangible_products_number,
  SUM(s.QuantityInShipment) as shipped_items_number
FROM
( 
  Inventory i,
  ShoppingCart c
)
LEFT JOIN
  ShippedItems s
ON
  c.OrderID = s.OrderID
WHERE
  i.ProductID = c.ItemID AND
  i.IsDOwnloadable = 0 AND
  c.OrderID = t.OrderID AND
  s.CartID = c.ID
GROUP BY
  c.OrderID
HAVING
  SUM(c.Quantity) > SUM(s.QuantityInShipment)
```

The group by syntax will probably need to be adapted for SQL-Server

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The ShoppingCart table doesn't have and OrderID column. I've tried to getit to work in SQL-Server but wasn't able to.

Comment: I think your answer as lead me in the right direction. All i need to do now is make SUM(s.QuantityShipment) = 0 WHEN s.QuantityShipment = NULL. "HAVING 1 - NULL" is false. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because it got me in the right direction. The actual answer has been appended to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: You could do a `isnull(SUM(s.QuantityInShipment), 0)` instead of the case.. This will return 1st parameter if not null, or 2nd parameter if the 1st is null..

Answer (score 0):

Can you query dbo.Tracking where TrackingNumber is Null?  Would that give you the required information?

Comment: Well, TrackingNumber will never be null. the row isn't created unless an item is shipped. Also, just because we have a tracking number for an Order doesn't mean all of the order's items have been shipped.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a bit field OrderComplete?  If OrderComplete = 1 that means all items shipped.  Then your query would be select * from dbo.Orders where OrderComplete = 1 to obtain all orders that have had all items shipped.

Comment: I thought about that. It just seems like a non-relational thing to do. And to set the OrderComplete flag I'd have to cycle through the orders, items, quantities, etc in my programming layer. Which I also thought couldn't be a best practice.